# Riak: indexing and querying kv data

Tags: riak, riak-search

I would like to implement "indexing and querying kv data" as described in the Riak docs at http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/cookbooks/Riak-Search---Indexing-and-Querying-Riak-KV-Data/.

While there is a little documentation about how to setting up indexing using the HTTP API, the documentation of basho lacks any information on how to query such indexed kv data using the HTTP API. Apparently it is not working like when i index contents from the file system, at least i did not get it to work like that.

Could anybody help in posting some simple examples using cURL? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying Riak Search over HTTP I believe you have 2 options, [which are described in greater detail here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/cookbooks/Riak-Search---Querying/). The easiest one is probably to use the Solr compatible interface, but it is also possible to feed Riak Search results to a MapReduce job and get the results that way.

Comment: yes, the reason why i do not want to use mapreduce is, that i would like to have some sort of paging, which isn't possible with mapreduce (at least not on riak side), but seems to be possible with this solr thing. however: the solr interface does not seem to work when indexing buckets. at least: using `bin/search-cmd install <bucket>` riak reports success, but there does not seem to be any solr interface to it. i tried with the examples already you mentioned, but the solr interface does not seem to be there.

Comment: ok, found my problem: i did not enable solr search in app.config. then of course it just can't work. thanks again for your help!